# PHP check if exists in database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to check does something exists in my database. Basicly I want to add device for user if it does not exists, and I'm trying to do it like so:

```
public static function checkDevice($userId, $tokenId){
        $devices = UserDevices::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
    
        $notExists = '';

        foreach ($devices as $key => $d) {
            if(!$d->ip_address === SecureAgent::getIP() && $d->mac_address === SecureAgent::getMAC() && $d->device === SecureAgent::getDevice() ){
                $notExists = 'User device not found!';
            }
        }
   }
```

So I need to check is does this IP, Mac and Device are already added in database, if any of them is not similar like any else I will need them to add in database like:

```
if($notExists === 'User device not found'){
  self::addDevice() // I'm calling another function to do that job
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't do this through PHP. Query for it in the database instead. Otherwise, you're doing the check wrong. You want to write the flag only if the device is found. Otherwise, you're going to overwrite it on each loop if there are multiple devices.

Comment: Like so: UserDevices::where('user_id', $userId)->where('ip_address', SecureAgent::getIp) etc... ?

Comment: Correct. You can then use `count()` instead of `get()` just to get the number of rows that match.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like so:

```
try {
            UserDevices::where('user_id', $userId)->where('ip_address', SecureAgent::getIP())->where('mac_address', SecureAgent::getMac())->where('browser', SecureAgent::getSurfer())->firstOrFail();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            self::addDevice($userId, $tokenId);
        }
```